# Alors que / lorsque je sors de la classe

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

> Valérian a le dos tourné, mais il entend bien sûr le bruit de mes pas
> et jette un regard rapide dans ma direction **alors que** je sors de la
> classe en refermant doucement la porte derrière moi.

Donc, "alors que" signifie "pendant que", "tandis que je sors de la classe", "lors de ma sortie", et "lorsque" signifie que le narrateur est sorti, Valérian lui a jeté un regard : l'action est rapide et elle est terminée ? Je ne comprends pas le rôle de "lorsque" ici, est-ce qu'il signifie "après" ?

Answer (score 3):

***Lorsque*** ne signifie jamais *après* mais indique une simultanéité.

***Alors que*** et ***lorsque*** sont donc ici synonymes mais le premier est plus soutenu (en France) quand il a ce sens.

***Alors que*** peut aussi signifier une opposition comme par exemple :

> Valérian jette un regard dans ma direction **alors que** moi, je regarde ailleurs.

> *Il vivait si simplement qu'on ne soupçonnait pas à quel point il était riche, et l'eût-on su qu'on se fût trompé encore, l'ayant cru alors avare, **alors que** personne ne fut jamais si généreux.* Marcel Proust, *La prisonnière*, 1927.

Comment: Merci. _Lorsque ne signifie jamais après mais indique une simultanéité_.  Oui ? Prenons par exemple, la phrase suivante : _Lorsque je suis rentrée à la maison, j'ai allumé la télévision._ Là, la première action (rentrer à la maison) est terminée, lorsque je me tourne vers la télévision. Je comprends ce que signifie "alors que", par contre, j'ai du mal à comprendre "la vraie signification" de "lorsque", notamment dans ma phrase. Donc, d'après toi, les deux options sont possibles ici ?

Comment: *Lorsque* est interchangeable avec *quand* dans ton exemple: *Quand je suis rentrée à la maison, j'ai allumé la télé*. Ici, *rentrer à la maison* n'est pas un événement instantané, le passage de la porte d'entrée, mais une période qui précède (parce qu'il est écrit ***à** la maison*, pas ***dans** la maison*) et suit ce passage. (*Lorsque je suis rentrée à la maison, je me suis fait flasher par un radar sur l'autoroute*). Si on veut indiquer une séquence d'événements, on pourra dire : *après être rentrée à la maison, j'ai allumé la télé* ou *Un fois rentrée à la maison,...*,

Comment: _Lorsque_ est toujours interchangeable avec _quand_, non ? Je ne comprends pas, si _rentrer à la maison_ n'est pas un événement instantané, il faut employer _alors que_ ou _tandis que_ à la place, non ?

Comment: 1. Pas interchangeable dans une interrogative: (*Tu viens quand ?*).  2. Rien n'interdit d'utiliser *lorsque* pour un événement qui dure: *Lorsque j'étais enfant, sortant de rhétorique, J'envoyais aux journaux de la prose lyrique*, Victor Hugo.